# Add a tag to word jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<style>span{color:red;}</style>

<div>John Resig</div>
<div>George Martin</div>
<div>Malcom John Sinclair</div>
<div>J. Ohn</div>
<div id="msg">Sample text</div>
```

---

```
<script>
$( "div:contains('John')" ).append('<span></span>').show();
</script>
```

How to add span tag to a word? is it possible? I am trying to search a word in content and if its available then that words should be highlight.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tm6SH/58/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a callback to `html()` and use `replace()`.

```
$( "div:contains('John')" ).html(function(i,html){
    return html.replace(/(John)/g,'<span>$1</span>')
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qrfavop2/)**

```
var word = 'John';
$( "div:contains('"+word+"')" ).html(function(i,html){
    var re = new RegExp(word,"g");
    return html.replace(re,'<span>'+word+'</span>')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
$('div').each(function(){
   $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/(John)/g,'<span>$1</span>'));
});
```